# Can we change the parameter of Find-DbaAgentJob?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

Can we change the parameter of Find-DbaAgentJob?

Hi there,

I got "[Find-DbaAgentJob] Failure | Error connecting to [xxx.yyy.zzz]: The certificate chain was issued by an authori
ty that is not trusted" error msg and it cannot connect with my SQL Server.

So I used debug with the Find-DbaAgentJob and found:

The masked server.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString is Data Source=xxx.yyy.zzz;Integrated Security=True;Multiple Active Result Sets=False;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name="dbatools PowerShell module - dbatools.io"

The key is "Trust Server Certificate=False".

Do we have the option to change this to "Trust Server Certificate=True"?

Or you have any other suggestions?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour in dbatools when connecting is to set that property to false. To override this, first create a server object using [Connect-DbaInstance](https://docs.dbatools.io/Connect-DbaInstance). This object can then be used in Find-DbaAgentJob in the SqlInstance parameter.

Example:

```
$server = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance sql2016 -TrustServerCertificate
Find-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance $server -JobName *backup*
```

Comment: Thank you very much HandyD! It works! Appreciated!